# C - Verify access of a file's directory

Tags: c

I would like to check if I can create a file in a directory. This directory is the one where my `dst` file is. To know if I can create a file in a directory, this directory should have the `'w'` access.

I searched how to get the directory name of my file and found the `dirname(char *)` function. But this function modify the given string. I want to keep my `dst` string unchanged!

This code is working, but is not really clean, I wonder if there is another way to accomplish it.

```c
const char* dst = "directory/file";
char* dstDir = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(dst) + 1));
strcpy(dstDir, dst);
dirname(dstDir);

if (access(dstDir, W_OK) == -1) {
    perror(dstDir);
    free(dstDir);
    exit(1);
}
free(dstDir);
```

NB : Is it mandatory to use `malloc` here ?

Comment: It would be better to use separate pointer variables for the buffer (currently `dstDir`) and for the return value of `dirname`. That would also work when the string passed to `dirname` does not contain a slash (causing `dirname` to return `"."`). But make sure you free the pointer returned by `malloc` rather than the one returned by `dirname`!

Comment: I don't get it, the return value is not the same that the changed given string ? The `man` says that the pointer should not be modified or freed until the pointer returned by the function is no longer required. But I don't use it.

Comment: `dirname` can modify `dstDir` but it does not have to. It can return a pointer to some internal storage. I don't know if the returned string can be modified. (In particular when the man page says it returns `"."` it is not stated that the content of the returned string is modifiable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dirname` is a POSIX function, you should also be able to use the POSIX function `strdup` to allocate the copy of the string.

The `dirname` function does not necessarily return the pointer that was passed to it. It can point to some internal storage (either static or thread-local), and can be overwritten by a subsequent call to `dirname`.

With the above in mind, I suggest the following:

```
const char* dst = "directory/file";
char* dstBuf = strdup(dst);
if (!dstBuf) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n");
    exit(1);
}
char* dstDir = dirname(dstBuf);

if (access(dstDir, W_OK) == -1) {
    perror(dstDir);
    free(dstBuf);
    exit(1);
}
free(dstBuf);
```

An alternative to using dynamically allocated buffer for the copy of the string is to use a variable length array (VLA). This alternative is shown below:

```
const char* dst = "directory/file";
char dstBuf[strlen(dst) + 1];
strcpy(dstBuf, dst);
char* dstDir = dirname(dstBuf);

if (access(dstDir, W_OK) == -1) {
    perror(dstDir);
    exit(1);
}
```

However, VLA support is optional in the C standard and is not part of the C++17 standard.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is more complicated that what i've done but if there is no other way

Comment: @Ephesiel Well an alternative would be to use a variable length array (VLA). I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: I have this warning `ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘dstBuf’`

Comment: @Ephesiel True, variable length arrays are not part of the C++ standard. I've added a note about that to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static char array.

```
char dstDir[LARGE_ENOUGH_BUF_SIZE] = "\0";
dirname(strcat(dstDir, dst));
//...
```

Comment: Yes I could indeed, but what is a `LARGE_ENOUGH_BUF_SIZE` ? Is it not better if my code works for all possibilities? Is a static array of 2048 char for example better than an adaptable `malloc`?

Comment: This was an answer to your question whether it is mandatory to use malloc. And yes, the buffer has to be large enough for every possible case. Well, a large enough buffer size 'might' be better than allocating and freeing a block of memory, it depends. Calling malloc has its side effects, a static block only consumes a specific size on the stack.